# Creating an array of structures with data entered by the user

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, struct

I have an assignment where I need to create a program that explores FIFO queues. The task is to create a array in which each element holds 2 numbers x and y.
And then you have to have a push, pop and show methods that inserts a new element, deletes an element and shows all the current elements in the queue.

I tried adapting a basic queue system to my needs, but I had trouble with the part where you have to have 2 values for each element (x and y).

My latest attempt is with structures. But Im having trouble understanding how I would create a structure every time an option to add (push) data in is selected. And then returning all the values that are currently saved in the array of structures.
If this is even possible.

Here is what I have so far:
queue.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "queue.h"
#include <array>
using namespace std;

queue::queue(){
    int length;
    cout <<"Queue max length: ";
    cin >> length;
    cout <<"\n";

    int array[length];
    capacity = length;
}

void queue::push(){
     struct Coordinates{ //And this whole part wont work either cause I need to create a structure before I can enter data into it. 
//I assume I need to use a for loop in order to createa strcutre everytype the 'push' method is called?
            int x;
            int y;
        }arr[capacity];

for (i = 0; i<capacity; i++){ //Something like this to createa a struct for each array element?

}

    cout << "Please enter the desired values (x, y): ";
    cin >> Coordinates.x >> Coordinates.y;
    cout <<"\n" << "You entered: " <<Coordinates[1]; //This is obviously wrong, I dont actually get how I will print the structures that are saved in the array? And how will I tell the program to assign the values to the first array element, the second, the third etc..?
}
```

queue.h:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H
#include <iostream>

class queue
{
    public:
        queue();
        virtual ~queue();
        void push();
        void pop();
        void show() const;

    private:
        int capacity;
};

#endif // QUEUE_H
```

I apologise if its too lengthy, I thought If I shortened it, it wouldnt make sense.

The expected end result should look like this:

```
Please enter the size of the queue: 15

What would you like to do? + (positive being they have to enter two new numbers)
Please enter the coordinates to be saved: 5,4

What would you like to do? + (again)
Please enter the coordinates to be saved: 3,5

What would you like to do? * (star being show method)

(Show method) The current Queue is: {5,4}, {3,5};


What would you like to do? - (negative being dequeue)

(Show method) The current Queue is: {3,5};


What would you like to do? + (positive being they have to enter two new numbers)
Please enter the coordinates to be saved: 7,8

(Show method) The current Queue is: {3,5}; {7,8};

And so forth. I hope this explains the end results.
```

Any suggestions, or pointers to what Im doing wrong would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method globally and then use an array of it inside your queue class. You don't have to create it every time you call the push method.
Create a private iterator inside the class. And inside the push function, you can just take input and add it to the iterator no. element in the Structure array.

Such as if you take an array of struct Coordinates inside your class and take an integer iterator, i to keep track of the current position in the array, you can just simply take input like this:

`cin >> Coordinates[i].x >> Coordinates[i].y, i++;`